# How to make lib files available to user in package recipe?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm creating a conan package for OpenCV but am at a loss on what to put in `package_info`. Building OpenCV places `.lib` and `.dll` files in the paths `x64\vc15\lib` and `x64\vc15\bin`. This means that once I install the package and try to link I get linker errors as Visual C++ cannot find the files.

What is the correct way of making these files available to Visual Studio? Should I add code to the `package` method to move the bin and lib directories out of x64 and into `package_folder` or should I add code to `package_info` to indicate the path to those directories via `self.cpp_info.libdirs`?

Comment: First all, don't remove this question! The last two questions you just removed after receiving an answer. There is a well implemented package for OpenCV: https://github.com/conan-community/conan-opencv you can take it as base for your study. All .dll files should be available in \bin by convention, and all .lib should be available in \lib. You need to copy from where they are to self.package_folder\bin and self.package_folder\lib

Comment: Also, as you are dealing with shared libraries, you can take look here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_shared_libraries/env_vars.html

Comment: I removed the questions because they did not make sense. At least to me.